# How to send an email in a separate process with codeigniter

Tags: php, email, codeigniter-3

I have an error reporting function in a web application, and when a user posts an error, an email sends out to the developer email. Current workflow is like `user input -> db write -> send email -> redirect`.

To prevent the email function holding back the rest of the user process, I want to separate it, so the email sending process can do their thing but the users can keep working. So its like

```
user input -> db write --> redirect
                       \-> send email
```

First thing that came into my mind is that I send an ajax request to start the email process so the error reporting and the email function can work asynchronously, but I'm curious if there would be a better way to do this.

Comment: Before you do anything, ask yourself if such additional complexity is necessary or maybe you are trying to optimize prematurely. Maybe simple Ajax request and an indicator would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do this depending on how complex you want to get. PHP does have process control stuff, but especially if your site is going to be hosted on a shared hosting provider, the availability of that functionality in your hosting environment is not guaranteed.

Probably one of the more foolproof ways to do this in terms of ensuring compatibility across a wide range of hosting environments is to start a new "mails to send" database table and log a row to that for each mail you want to send. Then set up a cron task on your server which runs a script which pulls all rows from this table, sends the email, then removes the row from the table. With CodeIgniter, if you call the `index.php` script like

`php -f index.php foo bar`

it will call the same method that would be called if the `/foo/bar` path is called via the standard routing system (eg, the `bar` method of the `Foo` controller). Then, inside that method, you can use `if (!is_cli()) { exit(); }` to make sure that method isn't being called from a web request, and [`flock()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) to make sure you don't have two processes sending emails at one time (in case one hangs or takes a long time or something). Select everything from the "mails to send" table, iterate through them row by row, send the mail, do some logging if applicable, then delete the row. ([More info on doing CLI scripts on CodeIgniter.](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/cli.html))

Then set up a cron task to run this script every X minutes, perhaps set up some way to check the table now and then to make sure it's not growing too large (which would be a sign that the mail sending script is failing somehow), and there you go.

As mentioned above, there are more clever ways to implement something like this, but this is a fairly broadly-compatible and foolproof one.

Comment: This was my second thought, the only reason I reject it for the first time is that it's not sending immediately. But I know that I have this opportunity at my hosting provider, and if no easier solution exists, probably this will be the winner solution

Answer (score 1):

Forking off a process from a PHP script that is handling a web server request is possible, but you should be wary of a few things:

- Your original PHP process and the forked off process will probably share a lot of data objects. While some variables may be copied and can be manipulated independently in the child and parent processes, some vars (like db connections or file handles, etc.) may refer to the same computing resource. You should be careful to avoid re-using resource variables. Have the child reconnect to your db and re open files, etc.
- If a process forks off, it might have trouble connecting to a db or mail gateway, etc. You should probably make this forked child process loop to try and accomplish its goal and then eventually die after a certain number of attempts if it's doing something important.
- There are probably a dozen other warnings about multithreading, race conditions, resource usage, etc. Just remember that forking off processes means that you are consuming more resources, that those resources might be in use by other processes, and you might get weird, hard-to-troubleshoot problems.

All that said, I have had some luck using a combination of the [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) command to fork off a separate process and then calling the [posix_setsid](https://php.net/posix_setsid) function so that the forked-off child process can fully detach itself from apache and continue running even if the parent process finishes or apache restarts or whatever.

**USE THIS CODE AT YOUR OWN RISK.**

From your CodeIgniter script, you can fork off a child process using exec, like so:

```
// the PARENT process (a CodeIgniter script running in response to http request)
// put this code in a controller or something

// here's a command to run the PHP executable in the background on some file
// routing the output and error messages to another file
$cmd = "/usr/bin/php /path/to/child-script.php > /tmp/foo/out.txt 2>&1 & echo \$!";

// will contain an array of output lines from the exec command
$cmd_output = NULL;

// will contain the success/failure code returned by the OS.
// Will be zero for a valid command, non-zero otherwise
$cmd_result = NULL; 

// $return will contain the last line from the result of
// the command which should be the PID of the process we have spawned
$cmd_return = exec ( $cmd, $cmd_output, $cmd_result );
```

NOTE: that you could instead use [pcntl_fork](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) to fork off the process. The reason I have not is because that means the child process would inherit *every variable in the codeigniter parent script* which can lead to some confusing behavior. E.g., if one process changes the db connection, that change might suddenly appear in the other script, etc. The use of exec() here more thoroughly separates the two scripts and makes things simpler. If you want to change $cmd above to run a CodeIgniter controller, see [CodeIgniter from the Command Line](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html).

In the child process, you must call posix_setsid() so that the child script detaches itself from the parent. If you do not, then the child process might be killed when the parent process finishes (or is killed) or if the web server restarts or crashes or whatever.

Here is the code in the child process, which requires the POSIX extension to be installed, enabled, and not disabled in PHP.ini by the [disable_functions](http://php.net/disable-functions) directive. This extension is very often disabled (and for good reason) in your web server's PHP.ini, but sometimes still available for CLI scripts. Another good reason to use exec to fork off a command-line process.

```
// child-script.php
// CHILD process. Put your emailing code or other long-running junk in here
// because this is a brand-new, separate process, you might need to load configuration files, connect to the db, etc.

if (!extension_loaded("posix")){
    throw new Exception("This script requires posix extension");
}

// NOTE: the output and results of this file will be completely unavailable to the parent script and you might never know what happens if you don't write a log file or something. Consider opening a log file somewhere

// process id of this process, should match contents of $cmd_return above
$mypid = posix_getpid();

// session id -- not to be confused with php session id
// apparently this call will make this process a 'session leader'
$sid = posix_setsid();
if ($sid < 0) {
    throw new Exception("setsid failed, returned $sid");
} 

// this output should be routed by the exec command above to
// /tmp/foo/out.txt
echo "setsid success, sid=$sid\n";

// PUT YOUR EMAILING CODE HERE
```

Comment: Well, thank you for your well detailed answer, but it seems to me an overkill solution for what I need, but probably I will try it in a local environment just to see how it works